# What do you call it when the errors lead you in the wrong direction?

Tags: terminology

I do tech support for a living.  Occasionally, I run into a series of circumstances that leads me and/or the other technician I am working with down the wrong rabbit hole, in the wrong direction, and/or far off base; the solution has little to do with the indicators that we consult (errors, log files, etc).  I also run into this phenomenon while doing random projects like Raspberry Pi stuff.  Is there a name for such a phenomenon?

For example, an error message in the software I support that frequently starts a support call says there is an error checking licensing.  Most people take the error at face value and assume that something is wrong with their license for the software, sometimes telling us there was an error and sometimes not.  From the software's and/or developer's perspective, the error is not wrong, but from a user perspective it starts you down the wrong path immediately.

Usually the actual problem is that there is some form of communication problem or permission problem accessing the application's database.  The error about not being able to check the license is displayed because the application cannot access the database to check if the license is there.

Is there a name for this phenomenon?  I didn't see a philosophy tag, nor a better Stack Exchange to ask about this on, so I asked it here on SuperUser.

Comment: I'd use _red herring_ to describe something like this.

Comment: I'd use analysis.

Comment: Welcome to the world of troubleshooting. :)

Comment: I think I call that phenomenon "Monday". :)  Joking aside, I'm not sure I have an answer, but perhaps the idiom "Wild Goose Chase" is fitting.

Comment: I think red herring is probably what I am looking for.  Not sure how I had a big enough brain fart to make a whole question out of it though lol.  I blame Linux, since I just spent 8 hours troubleshooting Raspbian.

Comment: Its called the communication-comprehension paradox, then I have my morning caffeine stimulant....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *red herring*.

> Something, especially a clue, that is or is intended to be misleading
>   or distracting - Oxford Dictionary

(Source: [Oxford American English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/red-herring))

In this case the example error message is not intended to be misleading but nevertheless is!